# Integrating Eulersharp with Cliopatria

Tags: prolog, semantic-web, n3, eulersharp, cliopatria

I would like to use the [Cliopatria](http://cliopatria.swi-prolog.org/home) Semantic Web Server however I am currently making extensive use of n3-rules using [EulerSharp](http://eulersharp.sourceforge.net/). I don't want to lose the termination guarantees provided by n3, but I would like to serve the resulting graphs via ClioPatria without having to run periodic external scripts.

Given both ClioPatria and EulerSharp run on SWI-Prolog I was wondering if anyone had any experience trying to combine the two projects within the same web-application?

Comment: Consider to ask this question on the SWI-list.